# How can I change null values in two columns for two random numbers between the min and the max of those columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

I have the following columns in my dataset in pandas:

```
Index(['Country', 'Region', 'Happiness Rank', 'Happiness Score',
       'Lower Confidence Interval', 'Upper Confidence Interval',
       'Economy (GDP per Capita)', 'Family', 'Health (Life Expectancy)',
       'Freedom', 'Trust (Government Corruption)', 'Generosity',
       'Dystopia Residual'],
      dtype='object')
```

I need to change the null values from columns "Lower Confidence Interval" and "Upper Confidence Interval" to a random number between the minimum and the maximum value of each column. The values in both columns are both integers with decimals.

This is what I've tried:

```
import random

print(random.randint((df.max(axis=0)["Lower Confidence Interval"]),(df.mmin(axis=0)["Lower Confidence Interval"])(df.max(axis=0)["Upper Confidence Interval"]),(df.mmin(axis=0)["Upper Confidence Interval"])

df.loc[:, ["Lower Confidence Interval", "Upper Confidence Interval"]].fillna(5, inplace=True)
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
 File "<ipython-input-100-e3190b8f67a4>", line 1
    print(random.randint((df.max(axis=0)["Lower Confidence Interval"]),(df.mmin(axis=0)["Lower Confidence Interval"])(df.max(axis=0)["Upper Confidence Interval"]),(df.mmin(axis=0)["Upper Confidence Interval"])
                                                                                                                                                                                                               
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I've been stuck here for a while and can't get past this error. Anyone any clue?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Check your parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use this hypothetical dataset, `df`:

```
   sample_col
0         nan
1         nan
2        4.41
3        9.79
4        8.24
5        7.04
6        4.41
7        4.09
8        5.58
9        6.34
```

You can create `int` objects called **use_min** and **use_max**, which will be derived from the `min()` and `max()` values of your column at hand.

```
use_min , use_max = int(df['sample_col'].min()) , int(df['sample_col'].max())
```

Then, you can `fillna` with using `random.randint` ( allows you to generate random numbers) which takes as arguments a min value and max value, which can be your `use_min , use_max`

```
import random
df['sample_col'].fillna(random.randint(use_min,use_max))

Out[342]: 
0   6.00
1   6.00
2   4.41
3   9.79
4   8.24
5   7.04
6   4.41
7   4.09
8   5.58
9   6.34
Name: sample_col, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works to avoid the error but it doesn't get me the random number between the min and the max. What I'm trying to avoid is having to choose the name I want to fill in manually.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I provided a new answer. Hopefully this will get you what you need.

Comment: It does! Thanks a lot for the quick help!